# R join or merge don't duplicate non-joining columns (reproducible)

Tags: r, join, merge

**This is different from the marked duplicate because I have to dynamically merge the column values removing NA, while merging**

**I can't use datatxt1 or datatxt2 as merging columns since (as I outline below) df1 and df2 come in from a function that may or may not contain those columns. The data sample below is a sample of what the data could be, not a finality. This is the issue with answers below**

**Original Question**

How do I get any join or merge command to a(if a column exists in two sets: combine columns overriding NA if a value exists in either vector but merging equal values in each vector, b(exists in one set: keep the column as is including NA in the output, or c(doesn't exist in either set: not include in the output. I have one consistent column every time in both sets to index and merge on (ID_2 in the data examples).

Basically I need to merge on ID_2 two sets accounting for the possibility of combining columns, and those needing to be combined before the merge.

**Say I Have Data Like This:**

```
 df1 <- data.frame(
        ID_2=c("5", "9", "20", "6", "8"),
        datatxt1=c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"),
        datatxt2=c("text1","text2","text3","text4","text5"),
        datan= c(1,2,3,4,5),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                       )

df2 <- data.frame(
        ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
        datatxt1=c(rep("NA",20), rep("data2",20), rep("data4",20)),
        datatxt2=c(rep("text1",20), rep("text2",20), rep("text4",20)),
        adddatan= c(rep(500,20),rep(400,20),rep(300,20)),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                       )
```

**What is the JOIN or MERGE command that will give me data like this?**

```
df.desired <- data.frame(
                ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
                datatxt1=c(rep("data1",20), rep("data2",20), rep("data4",20)),
                datatxt2=c(rep("text1",20), rep("text2",20), rep("text4",20)),
                datan=c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20), rep(4,20)),
                adddatan= c(rep(500,20),rep(400,20),rep(300,20)),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                   )
```

**Reasoning:**

1.In a larger function I have a data frame being loaded within the function. I won't always have datapoints within common columns (so I can't merge on them), but I'd like to keep them if I have them in both but correct them based on the lookup, and keep one column name with the data together while merging on a separate common column.

***UPDATE***

**Additional data examples where I also need it to work at the request of clarification. I also need it to work where datatxt1 is the complete column, both are incomplete, one column is missing, or both are missing**

```
##Supplemental Example 1

df3 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c("5", "9", "20", "6", "8"),
  datatxt1=c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"),
  datatxt2=c("text1","text2","text3","text4","text5"),
  datan= c(1,2,3,4,5),
  adddatan= c(NA,200,100,300,500),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


df4 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
  datatxt1=c(rep("data1",20), rep("data2",20), rep("data4",20)),
  datatxt2=c(rep("text1",20), rep(NA,20), rep("text4",20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(500,20),rep(NA,20),rep(300,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)         



df.desired34 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
  datatxt1=c(rep("data1",20), rep("data2",20), rep("data4",20)),
  datatxt2=c(rep("text1",20), rep("text2",20), rep("text4",20)),
  datan=c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20), rep(4,20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(500,20),rep(200,20),rep(300,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)  

###Supplemental Example 2


df5 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c("5", "9", "20", "6", "8"),
  datatxt1=c("data1","data2","data3","data4","data5"),
  datan= c(1,2,3,4,5),
  adddatan= c(100,200,300,NA,500),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


df6 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("20",20),rep( "6",20), rep("8",20)),
  datatxt2=c(rep("text3",20), rep(NA,20), rep("text5",20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(300,20),rep(NA,20),rep(500,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)         



df.desired56 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("20",20),rep( "6",20), rep("8",20)),
  datatxt1=c(rep("data3",20), rep("data4",20), rep("data5",20)),
  datatxt2=c(rep("text3",20), rep(NA,20), rep("text5",20)),
  datan=c(rep(3,20), rep(4,20), rep(5,20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(300,20),rep(NA,20),rep(500,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) 

##Supplemental Example 3

df7 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c("5", "9", "20", "6", "8"),
  datatxt1=c("data1","data2","data3",NA,"data5"),
  datan= c(1,2,3,4,5),
  adddatan= c(100,200,300,400,500),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


df8 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
  datatxt1=c(rep("data1",20), rep("data2",20), rep(NA,20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(100,20),rep(200,20),rep(400,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)         



df.desired78 <- data.frame(
  ID_2=c(rep("5",20),rep( "9",20), rep("6",20)),
  datatxt1=c(rep("data1",20), rep("data2",20), rep(NA,20)),
  datan=c(rep(1,20), rep(2,20), rep(4,20)),
  adddatan= c(rep(100,20),rep(200,20),rep(400,20)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to join on datatxt1 without adding the rest of the non-common columns in the end results?

Comment: May be you are looking for `semi_join`

Comment: A `dplyr::left_join` will by default act on as many columns as the datasets have in common, if you don't specify using `by =`. If each set has `ID_2`, `datatxt1` and `datatxt2`, it will join on those. If one set has `datatxt2` missing, it will join on the two common columns. So it sounds like what you want happens by default anyway?

Comment: @neilfws, yes, but if there is a column like datatxt1 that is half incomplete it'll try to merge on that and it'll end up incomplete on the merge, but I also don't know for sure that datatxt1 even exists, so completing the case is an interesting problem prior to merging

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your expected output. For example, what's the logic behind the rows with `ID_2 == 20` in `df.desired`? The other column values do not seem to match any entries in `df1`. Could you please double-check that your expected output is correct.

That aside, this almost reproduces your expected outcome:

```
library(tidyverse);
df <- df2 %>%
    left_join(df1, by = c("ID_2", "datatxt2")) %>%
    select(ID_2, datatxt1.y, datatxt2, datan, adddatan) %>%
    rename(datatxt1 = datatxt1.y)
```

Explanation: Do a `left_join` of `df2` and `df1`, then select and rename columns to be consistent with your expected outcome. Note that `datatxt1 = datatxt1.y` replaces `datatxt1` entries from `df2` with entries from `df1`.

---

### Update

Merge only on `ID_2`, and then fill `datatxt2` conditional on whether `datatxt2` is not `NA` in `df1` or `df2`.

```
df <- df2 %>%
    left_join(df1, by = c("ID_2")) %>%
    mutate(datatxt2 = ifelse(is.na(datatxt2.x), datatxt2.y, datatxt2.x)) %>%
    select(ID_2, datatxt1.y, datatxt2, datan, adddatan) %>%
    rename(datatxt1 = datatxt1.y);
```

`df` is identical to `df.desired`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, ID was supposed to be consistent and wasn't with the 20, maybe more clear with the edit.

Comment: @NealBarsch So my solution does in fact reproduce your expected output, or am I missing something? `df` is the same as `df.desired` after your edit.

Comment: while it does in the exact example above, it doesn't quite for what I'm looking for. One problem I have is I don't know the complete cases, so I don't know that datatxt2 is complete while datatxt1 is not, so I can't know ahead of time that I should merge with datatxt2 as one of the merge columns

Comment: @NealBarsch I don't understand. It's difficult to help if the sample data you provide is not representative of your actual problem. Based on your sample data as it is, a simple `left_join` reproduces your expected output. Can you please edit your question to give *representative* and *minimal* sample data, otherwise this will turn into guess work.

Comment: It is representative, I just can't use datatxt1 or datatxt2 as a merge column as your function does because the merging df's (represented by df1 and df2) come in from a function with differing columns. There could be one or both of datatxt1 and datatxt2 or both could be missing, thus I can't merge with them and can only merge on ID which I know will be consistent

Comment: @NealBarsch *If* your data is representative, then this solution reproduces your expected output, and this should be marked as solved. Perhaps, we have a different interpretation of "representative sample". At the moment, I have no idea what you mean by *"I don't know that datatxt2 is complete while datatxt1 is not, so I can't know ahead of time that I should merge with datatxt2 as one of the merge columns"*.

Comment: It isn't solved because you ignored one of my necessary parameters that you cant merge on the datatxt2 column

Comment: What I meant by your quote above was for the given example. Did not mean to cause confusion. . . I edited it out. I was simply pointing out that in the case datatxt2 was complete and datatxt1 was not, **but I don't know that to be the case in my real life function**. It still said I can't merge on them. My fault if that caused the confusion though, not trying to create a rabbit hole of work here and I very much appreciate SO users like yourself to try and figure problems like this out

Comment: @NealBarsch All your `datatxt2` column entries **are** complete (in **both** `df1` and `df2`). That's why your sample data is **not representative** (according to your further elaborations)! Either way, I've edited my solution. Please take a look; this might be what you're after.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is they could be not complete. I'll post more sample data for another case if need be.  I need it to work if datatxt2 was the incomplete column and datatxt1 was complete, or if one existed and the other did not, or if neither existed at all.

Comment: @NealBarsch *"Yes, but what I'm saying is they could be not complete. I'll post more sample data for another case if need be."* Yes, that's what you shoud've done, and that's what is meant by a representative example. "Representative" as in it represents your actual problem in its details.

Comment: @NealBarsch So my updated solution is still not what you're after?

Comment: Yeah because there's still the possibility those columns don't exist which breaks that dplyr function, or which column if any will have NA. I put more example data up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for a dynamic join, if you are trying to determine whether to join on datatxt1 or datatxt2, below should be a minimal example I can think of to do it.

```
library(sqldf)

if (sum(is.na(df2$datatxt1)) > sum(is.na(df2$datatxt2))) {
  desire <- sqldf("select a.*,b.adddatan from df1 a join df2 b on a.id_2=b.id_2 and a.datatxt2=b.datatxt2")
} else {
  desire <- sqldf("select a.*,b.adddatan from df1 a join df2 b on 
a.id_2=b.id_2 and a.datatxt1=b.datatxt1")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is the same issue as the above answer. I don't know that datatxt2 will be complete and datatxt1 will be the column that needs fixing of NA values via df1. It could be the other way around, or I could have neither column, thus I can't merge on those columns