# How to merge or join dataframes in R and consolidate all columns with missing values?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I'm trying to merge two dataframes `df1` and `df2` using the key `id`.

These 2 dfs share a lot of the same column names, and when one value is missing in `df1$var`, for example, it's not missing in `df2$var`, and vice versa. I want the merged dataframe to have only 1 column for `var` rather than `var.x` and `var.y`.

When the values of both columns (e.g) `df1$var` and `df2$var` are not missing, however, they will always have the same value.

Also, I can't bind rows, because I need a many:one merge that keeps all observations, so I've been using `merge(..., all = T)` or `dplyr::full_join`.

Other solutions (like the one below) work when both dataframes only have a few columns that need to be consolidated.
[R join or merge don't duplicate non-joining columns (reproducible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185028/r-join-or-merge-dont-duplicate-non-joining-columns-reproducible)

Comment: Can you show a small repreoducible example with expeceted output.  Please use `dput`

Answer (score 1):

try `dplyr::rows_patch`, which only updates missing values:

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
df <- mtcars[,1:2] %>%mutate(id=row_number())
na_col1 <- sample(c(F,T),nrow(df),replace=T)  
na_col2 <- sample(c(F,T),nrow(df),replace=T)  
df1 <- df2 <- df
df1[na_col1,1] <- NA
df2[!na_col1,1] <- NA
df1[na_col2,2] <- NA
df2[!na_col2,2] <- NA

out <- rows_patch(df1,df2,by="id")

all.equal(df,out)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `dplyr::rows_patch()` to update only missing values, and `dplyr::rows_insert()` to add rows in `df2` that are missing from `df1`. The result will include all rows from both `df1` and `df2`, with `NA`s filled if there's a non-missing value in either `df1` or `df2`.

Using this example data:

```r
library(dplyr)

# missing values and no row for id "F"
(df1 <- data.frame(
  id = LETTERS[1:5],
  x = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 5),
  y = c(NA, 8, 9, NA, 11)
))
#   id  x  y
# 1  A  1 NA
# 2  B  2  8
# 3  C NA  9
# 4  D NA NA
# 5  E  5 11

# missing values and no row for id "E"
(df2 <- data.frame(
  id = LETTERS[c(1:4, 6)],
  x = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, 6),
  y = c(7, NA, NA, 10, 12)
))
#   id  x  y
# 1  A NA  7
# 2  B  2 NA
# 3  C  3 NA
# 4  D  4 10
# 5  F  6 12
```

You would do:

```r
# rows for all ids "A" - "F", with missing values filled
df1 %>% 
  rows_patch(df2, by = "id", unmatched = "ignore") %>% 
  rows_insert(df2, by = "id", conflict = "ignore")
#   id x  y
# 1  A 1  7
# 2  B 2  8
# 3  C 3  9
# 4  D 4 10
# 5  E 5 11
# 6  F 6 12
```